# MPI deadlock on linear reduction of trapezoid function

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm learning MPI and trying to modify trapezoid code from [Pacheco's Book](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~peter/) to use linear reduction, but I'm getting deadlocked after the N-1 process runs. I'm assuming it's because there's no way to ensure they're going in reverse order.

In short, for N processes, each process computes its integral. Process N sends its integral to N-1. Processes N-1 to 1 receive, sum, then send. Process 0 receives and totals.

Most of what's here is code from Pacheco. Mine is the if/else section.

```
/* trap.c -- Parallel Trapezoidal Rule, first version
 *
 * Input: None.
 * Output:  Estimate of the integral from a to b of f(x)
 *    using the trapezoidal rule and n trapezoids.
 *
 * Algorithm:
 *    1.  Each process calculates "its" interval of
 *        integration.
 *    2.  Each process estimates the integral of f(x)
 *        over its interval using the trapezoidal rule.
 *    3a. Each process != 0 sends its integral to 0.
 *    3b. Process 0 sums the calculations received from
 *        the individual processes and prints the result.
 *
 * Notes:
 *    1.  f(x), a, b, and n are all hardwired.
 *    2.  The number of processes (p) should evenly divide
 *        the number of trapezoids (n = 1024)
 *
 * See Chap. 4, pp. 56 & ff. in PPMPI.
 */
#include <stdio.h>

/* We'll be using MPI routines, definitions, etc. */
#include "mpi.h"


main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int         my_rank;                    /* My process rank              */
    int         p;                          /* The number of processes      */
    float       a = 0.0;                    /* Left endpoint                */
    float       b = 1.0;                    /* Right endpoint               */
    int         n = 1024;                   /* Number of trapezoids         */
    float       h;                          /* Trapezoid base length        */
    float       local_a;                    /* Left endpoint my process     */
    float       local_b;                    /* Right endpoint my process    */
    int         local_n;                    /* Number of trapezoids for     */
    /* my calculation                                                       */
    float       my_integral;                /* Integral over my interval    */
    float       received_interm_result;
    float       interm_result;              /* Each process' summed result  */
    float       total;                      /* Total integral               */
    int         source = my_rank + 1;       /* Process sending integral     */
    int         dest;                       /* All messages go to 0         */
    int         tag = 0;
    MPI_Status  status;

    float Trap(float local_a, float local_b, int local_n,
               float h);    /* Calculate local integral  */

    /* Let the system do what it needs to start up MPI */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Get my process rank */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    /* Find out how many processes are being used */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    h = (b-a)/n;    /* h is the same for all processes */
    local_n = n/p;  /* So is the number of trapezoids */

    /* Length of each process' interval of
     * integration = local_n*h.  So my interval
     * starts at: */
    local_a = a + my_rank*local_n*h;
    local_b = local_a + local_n*h;
    my_integral = Trap(local_a, local_b, local_n, h);

    if (my_rank == p-1) {               /* Last process only needs to send */
        dest = my_rank - 1;
        interm_result = my_integral;

        printf("Process %d interm result = %f\n", my_rank, interm_result);
        MPI_Send(&interm_result, 1, MPI_FLOAT, dest,
                 tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else if (my_rank != 0) {          /* Middle processes need to receive and send */
        dest = my_rank - 1;
        MPI_Recv(&received_interm_result, 1, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        interm_result = received_interm_result + my_integral;

        printf("Process %d interm result = %f\n", my_rank, interm_result);
        MPI_Send(&interm_result, 1, MPI_FLOAT, dest,
                 tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {                            /* Process 0 only needs to receive */
        MPI_Recv(&received_interm_result, 1, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        total = received_interm_result + my_integral;
        /* Print the result */
        printf("With n = %d trapezoids, our estimate\n",
               n);
        printf("of the integral from %f to %f = %f\n",
               a, b, total);
    }

    /* Shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize();
} /*  main  */


float Trap(
           float  local_a   /* in */,
           float  local_b   /* in */,
           int    local_n   /* in */,
           float  h         /* in */) {

    float integral;   /* Store result in integral  */
    float x;
    int i;

    float f(float x); /* function we're integrating */

    integral = (f(local_a) + f(local_b))/2.0;
    x = local_a;
    for (i = 1; i <= local_n-1; i++) {
        x = x + h;
        integral = integral + f(x);
    }
    integral = integral*h;
    return integral;
} /*  Trap  */


float f(float x) {
    float return_val;
    /* Calculate f(x). */
    /* Store calculation in return_val. */
    return_val = x*x;
    return return_val;
} /* f */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set source to `myrank+1` before getting the proper rank with `MPI_Comm_rank`, thus processes are probably waiting on the wrong processes to send them something.

I know you are doing this as an exercise, but to anybody looking to implementing this for production: you should consider using [MPI_Reduce](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node77.html), or if the partial results are relevant [MPI_Scan](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node84.html).